# cross platform unicode support

Tags: java, c, perl, unicode, cross-platform

I find that getting Unicode support in my cross-platform apps a real pain in the butt.

I need strings that can go from C code, to a database, to a Java application and into a Perl module.  Each of these use a different Unicode encodings (UTF8, UTF16) or some other code page.  The biggest thing that I need is a cross-platform way of doing conversions.

What kind of tools, libraries or techniques do people use to make handling these things easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://www.icu-project.org/

Answer (score 3):

Perl has [Encode](http://search.cpan.org/~dankogai/Encode/Encode.pm) as a standard library. It can be used to read/write any encoding you want, so that's not going to be a problem.

Comment: In fact Perl does not play so nicely with Windows APIs and filesystems which expect UTF-16. It's possible but not as trivial as you make it sound.

Answer (score 1):

How are you doing the cross-platform calls? Is it all called from Java?

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html might be useful.

I'm a bit confused about exactly what you are trying to do. Is the database essentially interface between all the code? Then it should be easy - just make the DB UTF-8 and each of the clients will need to do their own conversions.

Sounds like an interesting problem, could you share some more details?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess iconv is sufficient for your needs. Iconv should be available on any POSIX system by default (those include (GNU/)Linux, *BSD, Mac OS X...). On Windows AFAIK it requires separate library but:

1. you may just install it/bundle with your software/static compile it. ([libiconv for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm)). (I'd guess I'd recommend to bundle it).
2. You may use some native Windows calls as special case.

Of course if you are using Java it has it built-in - but I see that it may not be what you want (JNI calls are expensive).

PS. Cannot you set perl to specific encoding?